# Передать имя файла в другой клас

Tags: ios, swift, файлы, делегаты

У меня есть два ViewController'a и структура с названиями файлов.

В  VC1  надо выбрать какой файл будет использоватся путем нажатия на кнопку и передать его в VC2. У VC2 есть метод для считывания файлов с двумя параметрами. В параметр `name`  нужно передать имя файла для дальнейшей обработки. Я пробовал сделать это через `Protocol`, но это мне не помогло. Хотелось бы знать как это можна сделать с этим кодом. Спасибо

**FileName.swift**

```
struct FileName
{
   let easyFile:String = "easyFile"
   let hardFile:String = "hardFile"
}
```

**ChooseFile.swift**

```
class ChooseFile:UIViewController
{

//Здесь нужно в как то выбрать файл для использования и передать в ReadFile.swift
  @IBAction func chooseEasyFile(_ sender:UIButon)
{
   // выбрать easyFile

}
 @IBAction func chooseHardFile(_ sender:UIButon)
{
   // выбрать easyHard

}
```

**ReadFile.swift**

```
   class ReadFile:UIViewController
{
    let getFile = GetFile()

    func ShowContentFile()
{
    getFile.readFile(name://? ,type: "txt")
    //some code

 }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если VC1 вызывает VC2 напрямую через segue, то используем стандартный способ

- в VC2 создаем переменную для имени файла скажем `var fileName: String?`
- затем в VC1 можно создать такую же переменную для временного хранения выбранного по нажатию кнопок файла допустим `var selectedFileName: String?`
- вызываем `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` в методах кнопок
- в методе VC1 `prepare(for:sender:)` получаем экземпляр VC2 `let vc2 = segue.destination as! VC2`
- присваем имя файла `vc2.fileName = selectedFile`
- в VC2 работаем со значением например во `viewWillAppear`

Если использовать segue невозможно, можно использовать для сохранения значений общее хранилище - базу данных, `UserDefaults` и тд

Comment: Я не могу использовать segue, но как я мог забыть про UserDefaults. Для простого приложения это то что нужно. Спасибо !