# Swift. Запуск функции в одном VC из другого VC

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

В файле ViewController.swift есть два класса для контроллеров в main.storyboard - weekController и monthController.

По нажатию кнопки в monthController должна активироваться функция reinitializeMonth() в контроллере weekController, после monthController должен исчезнуть

Вот так я пытался это реализовать.

```
class monthController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectedMonth.month = String(sender.tag)
        weekController().reinitializeMonth()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

}
```

Но сразу выдаёт ошибку

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly
>   unwrapping an Optional value

на строчке

```
monthLabel.text = monthDict[month]!
```

Лейбл в weekController

Comment: А где и как у вас `monthDict` инициализируется?

Comment: `monthDict` инициализируются в самом начале weekController
Это [String:String]  словарь, константа

Comment: Я попробовал закомментировать эту строку, но выдаёт такую же ошибку, только уже на следующей строке, так что похоже что не в  monthDict дело

Comment: Посмотрите похожий вопрос, где сказано как передавать данные между вью контроллерами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087952/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81/1088040#1088040

Comment: Мне выдаёт ошибку 

`Use of unresolved identifier 'segue'`

Так же отличие от описанного в похожем случае в том, что monthController не вызывает weekController, а наоборот, сначала wC вызывает mC, а потом mC dismiss`ится, активируя функцию в wC. mC вызывается кнопкой на wC для считывания данных, на основе которых функция в wC обновляет интерфейс wC.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не совсем правильно организуете взаимодействие между вью контроллерами

Во-первых, по поводу стиля - вью контроллеры лучше держать в разных файлах и имена классов в Swift пишутся с большой буквы.

Во-вторых, касательно способов передачи данных между вью контроллерами. Есть разные способы, можете почитать самостоятельно, информации много, в вашем случае для передачи результата действия обратно в вызывающий вью контроллер можно использовать например (1) делегирование и (2) блок `completion`. При 2 способе данные придется сохранить в промежуточное хранилище, так как блок здесь не может иметь параметров.

Ваша ошибка состоит в том, что вы создаете экземпляр `weekController` заново вместо сохранения ссылки на уже существующий экземпляр

```
weekController().reinitializeMonth()
```

Пример

```
class WeekViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var monthLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func showMonthViewControllerButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "monthViewControllerIdentifier") as! MonthViewController
        // способ 1
        vc.delegate = self

        // способ 2
        vc.completion = {
            self.monthLabel.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "some_data")
        }

        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension WeekViewController : MonthViewControllerDelegate {

    func monthViewControllerWillDismiss(_ monthViewController: MonthViewController, with data: String) {
        monthLabel.text = data
    }

}
```

Возвращаем данные

```
protocol MonthViewControllerDelegate : class {

    func monthViewControllerWillDismiss(_ monthViewController: MonthViewController, with data: String)

}

class MonthViewController: UIViewController {

    // способ 1
    weak var delegate: MonthViewControllerDelegate?

    // способ 2
    var completion: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func dismissButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.monthViewControllerWillDismiss(self, with: "some data")

        UserDefaults.standard.set("some data", forKey: "some_data")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
    }

}
```